# Remove leading zeros from time to show elapsed time

Tags: c#, formatting, timespan

I need to display simplest version of elapsed time span. Is there any ready thing to do that?

Samples:

```
HH:mm:ss
10:43:27 > 10h43m27s
00:04:12 > 4m12s
00:00:07 > 7s
```

I think I need a format provider for elapsed time.

Comment: For reference: Existing Timespan formatters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simple extension method should be enough:

```
static class Extensions
{ 
    public static string ToShortForm(this TimeSpan t)
    {
        string shortForm = "";
        if (t.Hours > 0)
        {
            shortForm += string.Format("{0}h", t.Hours.ToString());
        }
        if (t.Minutes > 0)
        {
            shortForm += string.Format("{0}m", t.Minutes.ToString());
        }
        if (t.Seconds > 0)
        {
            shortForm += string.Format("{0}s", t.Seconds.ToString());
        }
        return shortForm;
    } 
}
```

Test it with:

```
TimeSpan tsTest = new TimeSpan(10, 43, 27);
string output = tsTest.ToShortForm();
tsTest = new TimeSpan(0, 4, 12);
output = tsTest.ToShortForm();
tsTest = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 7);
output = tsTest.ToShortForm();
```

Comment: P.S: It's not .NET v2.0 compatible.

Comment: In .NET v2.0, the C# style answer would be: `String.Format(new TimeSpanFormatProvider(), "Elapsed time is {0:ts}", timeSpan)`

Comment: This doesn't work for spans greater than 24 hours or less than one second.  For example a span of 26 hours (1 day, 2 hours) will return only as "2h".  A span of exactly 24 hours will return an empty string (no hours, minutes, or seconds). Add a check for days, or use `t.TotalHours` to show total elapsed hours. For spans of less than one second, check for an empty string at the end:`
`If String.IsNullOrEmpty(shortForm) Then
    shortForm = String.Format("{0}s", t.ToString("s\.ff"))
End If`

Answer (score 18):

Here's a one-liner (almost), assuming you have the `TimeSpan` objectL

```
(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 21, 3))
  .ToString(@"d\d\ hh\hmm\mss\s")
  .TrimStart(' ','d','h','m','s','0');
```

The sample code outputs

```
30m21s
```

The first line just makes a `TimeSpan` object for the sake of an example, `.ToString` formats it in the format you're asking for and then `.TrimStart` removes the leading characters you don't need.

Comment: great solution! how could we incorporate milliseconds to this one liner?

Comment: @justinpees `f` is for fractions of a second, you can add 3 for ms or more for mks:`(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30, 21, 3, 54))
  .ToString(@"d\d\ hh\hmm\mss\.ffffff\s")
  .TrimStart(' ', 'd', 'h', 'm', 's', '0')`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `string.Format` to achieve this, along with some conditional statements:

```
public static string GetSimplestTimeSpan(TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    var result = string.Empty;
    if (timeSpan.Days > 0)
    {
        result += string.Format(
            @"{0:ddd\d}", timeSpan).TrimStart('0');
    }
    if (timeSpan.Hours > 0)
    {
        result += string.Format(
            @"{0:hh\h}", timeSpan).TrimStart('0');
    }
    if (timeSpan.Minutes > 0)
    {
        result += string.Format(
            @"{0:mm\m}", timeSpan).TrimStart('0');
    }
    if (timeSpan.Seconds > 0)
    {
        result += string.Format(
            @"{0:ss\s}", timeSpan).TrimStart('0');
    }
    return result;
}
```

Though, seeing the answer by BrokenGlass I'm tempted to say using `Format` here at all is overkill. However, it does allow you to tweak the output of each element of the elapsed time span if required.

Comment: It doesn't trim zero day, hour, minute, etc... This is the result for 2s388f **:00:02.3881813**

Comment: Of course it does - `TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 2, 388);` results in `2s`. Though I could update it to account for milliseconds as right now it doesn't care about them due to the request being to display the _simplest_ form.

Comment: Strange; (TimeSpan){00:00:02.4100804} returns (String)":00:02.4100804" here -in .Net v2.0-

Comment: I stand corrected, tested myself and this is very definitely broken on .NET 2.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this can be done in a straightforward way doing a custom format serializer - I'd just roll my own:

```
TimeSpan delta = TimeSpan.Parse("09:03:07");
string displayTime = string.Empty;
if (delta.Hours > 0)
    displayTime += delta.Hours.ToString() + "h";

if (delta.Minutes > 0)
    displayTime += delta.Minutes.ToString() + "m";

if (delta.Seconds > 0)
    displayTime += delta.Seconds.ToString() + "s";
```

Note that this would only work for positive time spans.

Comment: I call this way as Indian style :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take:

```
    Dim TimeTaken As String = TimeSpan.ToString("g") ' Supply TimeSpan
    If TimeTaken.Contains("0:00") Then
        TimeTaken = TimeTaken.Remove(0, 3)
    ElseIf TimeTaken.Contains("0:0") Then
        TimeTaken = TimeTaken.Remove(0, 2)
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string ToFriendlyString(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    string result = string.Empty;

    if (Math.Floor(timeSpan.TotalDays) > 0.0d)
        result += string.Format(@"{0:ddd}d ", timeSpan).TrimFirst('0');
    if (Math.Floor(timeSpan.TotalHours) > 0.0d)
        result += string.Format(@"{0:hh}h ", timeSpan).TrimFirst('0');
    if (Math.Floor(timeSpan.TotalMinutes) > 0.0d)
        result += string.Format(@"{0:mm}m ", timeSpan).TrimFirst('0');
    if (Math.Floor(timeSpan.TotalSeconds) > 0.0d)
        result += string.Format(@"{0:ss}s ", timeSpan).TrimFirst('0');
    else
        result += "0s";

    return result;
}

public static string TrimFirst(this string value, char c)
{
    if (value[0] == c)
        return value[1..];

    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If any one need auto day string without elapsed zero.

You can try `toString("c")`

`new TimeSpan(41,48, 2, 3).ToString("c")`

will get result:

`43.00:02:03`

You can get more info in MSDN.
[TimeSpan.ToString Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.tostring?view=net-7.0)